# Ejecutar dos scripts con temporizador sin que uno pisotee al otro

Tags: python

Tengo dos programas en python con temporizador en time, uno se ejecuta cada 5m y el otro cada 30m lo que quiero es saber como tenerlos a los dos programados para ejecutarse, pero si uno se está ejecutando que no se ejecute el otro basicamente si coinciden en el tiempo que se espere a que el que empezó primero se ejecute y luego continue el otro pero sin perder el temporizador de cada uno, lo que hacen los programas es simple, basicamente escribe en el textbox de discord "x" cosa cada cierto tiempo y basicamente lo que quiero es evitar que ambos coincidan en el tiempo y se genere un doble tipeo.

```
import random
import pywinauto
import time
from pywinauto.application import Application
from pywinauto.keyboard import send_keys
import warnings
import keyboard
from datetime import datetime


while True:
    warnings.simplefilter('ignore', category=UserWarning)

    print("Este bot inicio a las:")

    now = datetime.now()
    print(now.strftime('%Y/%m/%d %I:%M:%S'))

    # iniciar discord
    app = Application().start(cmd_line=r"C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Discord\Update.exe --processStart Discord.exe")

    # Conectarse a la ventana
    win = Application().connect(title="General - Discord")

    # Escribir
    win[u"General"].type_keys("Hola", with_spaces=True, with_newlines=True, pause=0.1, with_tabs=True)
    print("Escribiendo")
    time.sleep(random.randint(2, 4))
    send_keys("{ENTER}")
    print("He escrito correctamente")

    time.sleep(random.randint(310, 315))
```

Comment: Bienvenido Brayan c: Podrías poner un ejemplo minimo y verificable para que sea más facil ayudarte?

Comment: Escribe un tercer programa que se llama cada 5 minutos. Este programa se encarga de llamar al de 5 min y/o 30 min en el orden correcto.

Comment: El del ejemplo seria mi archivo main.py con espera de 5 min, el otro seria el archivo main2.py con espera de 30m

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lo que buscas se llama un "cerrojo" o Lock. Suele implementarse mediante un fichero. La biblioteca estándar python te da  `fcntl.flock()` para crearlos, pero hay librerías de terceros, como [`filelock`](https://github.com/benediktschmitt/py-filelock) que simplifican el uso.

Mientras un proceso tenga el cerrojo bloqueado, el otro esperará. Tus dos programas deben por tanto intentar adquirir el cerrojo antes de escribir en discord. El que primero llegue a la línea en que se adquiere el cerrojo, podrá continuar, el que llegue después esperará a que el otro lo suelte.

Usando la librería `filelock` tu código se modificaría en la forma siguiente:

1. Se importa esa librería
2. Se crea un cerrojo (aparecerá como un fichero en tu sistema de archivos, estará vacío pero servirá para sincronizar los procesos)
3. Se mete la *sección crítica* dentro de un bloque `with lock`. La sección crítica es la parte de código que no se puede ejecutar a la vez en ambos procesos (la que escribe en discord). El bloque `with` intenta adquirir el cerrojo al entrar, y lo libera automáticamente al salir.

El código sería por tanto así:

```
import random
import Esperador
import pywinauto
import time
from pywinauto.application import Application
from pywinauto.keyboard import send_keys
import warnings
import keyboard
from datetime import datetime
from filelock import FileLock       # <----- Añadido

lock = FileLock("discord_bot_cerrojo.lock")  # <----- Añadido

while True:
    warnings.simplefilter('ignore', category=UserWarning)

    print("Este bot inicio a las:")

    now = datetime.now()
    print(now.strftime('%Y/%m/%d %I:%M:%S'))

    # iniciar discord
    app = Application().start(cmd_line=r"C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Discord\Update.exe --processStart Discord.exe")

    # Conectarse a la ventana
    win = Application().connect(title="General - Discord")

    # Escribir <------- Protegido ahora por el cerrojo
    with lock:
        win[u"General"].type_keys("Hola", with_spaces=True, with_newlines=True, pause=0.1, with_tabs=True)
        print("Escribiendo")
        time.sleep(random.randint(2, 4))
        send_keys("{ENTER}")
        print("He escrito correctamente")

    time.sleep(random.randint(310, 315))
```

Comment: Muchas gracias, nunca habia escuchado hablar del concepto, pero una duda, si ejecuto las aplicaciones de forma independiente(sin multithereado y eso) el cerrejo seguiria funcionando o hay que encapsular ambos .py en un solo script que los ejecute?.

Comment: Este cerrojo esta basado en un fichero, por lo que existe fuera de ambos scripts y por eso puede usarse para sincronizarlos aunque sean aplicaciones independientes. Si juntaras ambas en una sola multihilo habria otro tipo de cerrojos disponibles, en la propia libreria de threading.

Comment: ¡entiendo, lo probaré y leeré más sobre los distintos tipos de cerrojos, muchas gracias!